# jfreechart - setTicklabelFont is not working

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I am trying to change the font of the x-axis values (not the label) in a jfreechart bar chart.

```
    CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
    final CategoryAxis axis = p.getDomainAxis();
    Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 30);
    axis.setTicklabelFont(font);
```

I have imported the following packages:

```
    import org.jfree.chart.axis.Axis;
    import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
    import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions;
    import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
```

when i tried to compile the code, i am thrown with following error. Not sure which package i am missing. Or the way i am trying to change the font is wrong:

```
error: cannot find symbol
axis.setTicklabelFont(font);
    ^
symbol:   method setTicklabelFont(Font)
location: variable axis of type CategoryAxis
```

Comment: I dont know the reason for downvote here. Great !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mispelled the method name. It's `axis.setTickLabelFont(font);`

Please see javadoc:
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html